# Search for strings in a textarea which is contained inside a DIV

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, string, search

```
<div id="right_pane">
<textarea id="TextArea1"></textarea>
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
```

Hi, 
I have a text area and a submit button inside a DIV element. The input to the text area is going to be the source code of a website. I need to search and find number of Text box elements contained in the source code and display it to the user when the Submit button is clicked.
Can someone help me with the code?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: @kiiroSora09  -  I am new to HTML and asp.net. I am still in learning process and I don't currently have the idea to do this. I was hoping someone could help me with learning this.

Comment: when you say "Text Box" inside textarea ... what do you mean? You cannot introuce te

Comment: @MidhunT - Please provide an example of the source code.

Comment: @KiiroSsora- I want the app to scan source code of Websites like google, yahoo etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below. Since you did not provide a sample source code input, I only tested this with the below sample source code:

**Sample Source Code**

```
<div>
<input id="textbox1" type="text"/>
</div>
<input type="text" id="textbox2"/>
```

**Demo**

```js
var
$textarea = $('#TextArea1'),
$submit = $('#Submit1');

// Apply test input
$textarea.val('<div><input id="textbox1" type="text"/></div><input type="text" id="textbox2"/>');


$submit.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  sourceCode = $textarea.val();

  // Create jQuery object to insert and search the source code (from the textarea)
  var $searchObject = $('<div id="searchThis"></div>');

  // Append the source code (converted to a jQuery object)
  $searchObject.append($(sourceCode));

  // Search the object for occurrence of type="text" inputs
  alert($searchObject.find('[type=text]').length);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="right_pane">
  <textarea id="TextArea1"></textarea>
  <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
```

Comment: By the way, can I find number of dropdown lists (<select) in the source code?

Comment: Yes, just change this '$searchObject.find('[type=text]').length' to '$searchObject.find('select').length'. You really need to learn about jQuery selectors, since it's fundamental when you are using jQuery.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am a fresher and so i'm in the process of learning different languages. And yes, I will learn jQuery as soon as possible. Thanks again :)